# Como fazer uma div se expandir mesmo tendo outras embaixo

Tags: html, css

Bom pessoal, gostaria de fazer com que a div se expandi-se ao clicar nela, e as outras divs diminuíssem, em vice-versa com as outras

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.divsCards{
    position: relative;
    width: 420px;
    height: 480px;
    left: 45px;
    top: 25px;
    background-color: blueviolet;
}
.card{
    position: relative;
    width: 420px;
    height: 96px;
}
.card1{
    background-color: #feca57;
}
.card2{
    background-color: #0abde3;
}
.card3{
    background-color: #10ac84;
}
.card4{
    background-color: #54a0ff;
}
.card5{
    background-color: #723eda;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styleCardsRotinas.css">
        <title></title>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="divsCards">
            <div class="card card1"></div>
            <div class="card card2"></div>
            <div class="card card3"></div>
            <div class="card card4"></div>
            <div class="card card5"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Um dos truques mais úteis e legais que um desenvolvedor web pode aprender é usar DIVs expansíveis, também conhecidas como collapsible DIVs.

Esse efeito dá ao usuário a possibilidade de expor na página somente o conteúdo que ele quer ver naquele momento. Se eles estiverem interessados em ver os detalhes desse conteúdo, podem clicar em um link ou imagem e a página cresce dinamicamente para mostrar o conteúdo que ali estava “escondido”.

Vamos a prática!

```
<a href="javascript:;" onmousedown="toggleDiv('minha-div-1');">Toggle Div 1 Visibility</a>
  <div id="minha-div-1" style="display:none">
    <h3>This is a test!<br>Can you see me?</h3>
  </div><br />
    <a href="javascript:;" onmousedown="toggleDiv('minha-div-2');">Toggle Div 2 Visibility</a>
  <div id="minha-div-2" style="display:none">
     <h3>This is a test!<br>Can you see me?</h3>
 </div>
```

Agora copie o seguinte código em sua tag script

```
<script language="javascript">
  function toggleDiv(divid){
    if(document.getElementById(divid).style.display == 'none'){
      document.getElementById(divid).style.display = 'block';
    }else{
     document.getElementById(divid).style.display = 'none';
   }
 }
```

Fonte: rhodesignblog

https://rhodesignblog.wordpress.com/2008/12/15/como-criar-uma-div-expansivel-simples-com-javascript-e-css/

Comment: Entendi oq vc fez, mas como ficaria com css?

Comment: Você pode atribuir suas classes ao exemplo acima.

Comment: Obrigado cara, apesar de eu não usar o seu código pq eu consegui fazer de outra maneira, mas msm assim obrigado tmj :D